# Whats parameter for the function removeAnnotation

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know what is the parameter to send to `map.removeAnnotation();`?

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(["list"]);
```

Comment: Can you, at least, especify what class are we talking about? that method looks from IOS MKMapView to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have one class 
**onLocationChange**

```
        mapView.removeAnnotation('pin');

        glat = loc.getLatitude();
        glng = loc.getLongitude();

        //Setting the GPS Lat, Lng into the textView
        //textViewGpsLat.setText("GPS Latitude:  " + glat);
        //textViewGpsLng.setText("GPS Longitude:  " + glng);
        mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("pin").position(new LatLng(glat, glng)));


        Log.d("LAT & LNG GPS:", glat + " " + glng);
```

and class **showLoc**

```
        glocManager  = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        glocListener = new MyLocationListenerGPS();
        glocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 1, 0, glocListener);
```

I need to remove annotation, all the time that update update time